# Change of meaning: are words whose meaning has been "verschlechtert" preserved in Yiddish?

Tags: dialect, yiddish

In a [recent discussion](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/more-yiddish-es-lauft-die-jauch-die-millech-brennt/3033#3033) Grimm was quoted who describes Jauche as a word whose original meaning has been "verschlechtert". Interestingly, Yiddish preserves the original meaning, "broth". I know a few other examples where the nuance is different in the two languages, and I wonder if anyone can elaborate on these particular cases. I am thinking in particular of "zappelig", which in German is squirming or twitching, like a bug you would step on; in Yiddish, it is "throbbing", as the "zart, zappeldig leib" of a beautiful woman.

The other one is quite baffling: we have "abscheu"  (pr. opshay) as respect! I can guess it might have gone the direction of loathing => fear => respect, so if that is the pathway it is not really a case of "verschlechtering" but rather the opposite. Any ideas?

Comment: According to the Duden the origin of both words is unknown. Besides that I have to disagree with your translation of "zappelig". This one fits better: http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=zappelig

Comment: Which translation do you disagree with? I assure you that the Yiddish expression does not translate as the "tender, fidgety body" of a beautiful woman. Could the Yiddish phrase conceivably be used in German to describe a woman?

Comment: I disagree with your English translation (squirming, twitching). It has nothing to do with bugs. More with fidgety/unsettled children.

Comment: If you look at the recent discussion on Jauche, you will see that the concept of verschlechterung is not my invention; it comes from Grimm.

Comment: @fzwo: The OP is asking for an "elaboration" on how *zappelig* and *Abscheu* may have underwent pejoration in German vs. Yiddish. IMO this is quite clear from the question.

Comment: Yet another word pair of this type: Weib (more or less pejorative for "woman") vs. vayb (the original uncolored "wife", "woman").

Answer (score 3):

**Zappelig**

After having done some research I did not find any other meaning of "*zappeln*", *"zappelig"* than in the sense of something or someone moving fast back and forth or being restless. This meaning dates as far back as to old high german (according to Pfeifer):

> **zappeln** Vb. ‘(mit den Gliedmaßen, mit dem Körper) schnelle, unruhige Bewegungen machen’, ahd. *zabulōn* ‘sich unruhig bewegen, zucken’ (um 800), mhd. *zabel(e)n*, auch *zapeln* ‘mit den Gliedern zucken, ruhelos tätig sein’, frühnhd. *zabeln*, *zappeln* (16. Jh.), mundartlich auch *zabbeln*, *zawweln*; ein lautmalendes, bewegungsnachahmendes Wort. **zapp(e)lig** Adj. ‘sich unruhig (hin und her) bewegend, aufgeregt, innerlich unruhig’ (17. Jh.). <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=zappeln)</sup>

So in my opinion the Yiddish usage of *"zappelig"* in the meaning of *"throbbing"* may be figurative. If the orginial meaning is lost then this would rather be a Yiddish change for better than a worsening (*"Verschlechterung"*) of the meaning in German.

**[Grimm](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=zappeln)** list a single source where *"zappeln"* was used figuratively in the meaning of throbbing (*"pulsierend"*) in Musäus' *"[Melechsala](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Mus%C3%A4us,+Johann+Karl+August/M%C3%A4rchen/Volksm%C3%A4rchen+der+Deutschen/Melechsala)"*:

> »Soll mir Gott!« flüsterte der Arzt der Oberkämmerin ins Ohr, »mit Ihr Hoheit steht's schlecht: **der Puls zappelt** wie ein Mäuseschwanz«, und schüttelte, aus praktischer Politik, wie schlaue Ärzte pflegen, dabei gar bedenklich den Kopf, verordnete reichlich Kalaf und andere Herzstärkungen, und weissagte mit Achselzucken ein abzehrendes Fieber.

Still it was so uncommon that Musäus had to explain it by adding *"like a mouse tail"*.

Comment: Fascinating reference; however, the use of zappeln here is really not the same as our Yiddish usage. It's still in this example more of a twitching than a throbbing. We definitely do not use "zappeldig" for an annoying child, e.g. (BTW, I ought to clarify that the d in "zappeldig" is not a misprint, in case anyone doesn't recognize the Yiddish suffix.)

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that "verklemmt" is another word where the nuance shifts in a similar direction going from German to Yiddish. In German we have "prudish, uptight" where in Yiddish it is "emotionally choked up".

Comment: Please do not post follow-up questions / ammendments to the original question as an answer. Either open a new question, edit your OP or add a comment there.

Comment: It's not a follow-up question or an amendment. It's a new answer.